# Kint breaks in template and doesn't allow me to view anything

Tags: 8, debugging

In my template I am trying to view the contents of Childen in a form template.

```
<form{{ attributes }}>
  {{ kint(children) }}
</form>
```

However, the result I get is a useless broken kint message, that doesn't allow me to expand any of the fields or view any other information.

> [image: screenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of devel? Have you checked the PHP error log (unlikely there will be anything in there, but maybe worth checking)? And is there any weird content that is included in children?

Comment: Hm, try updating devel or use dump() instead of kint(). Personally I've never used kint/dsm from a template.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug report for a contributed module and must be filed as issue in the module's issue queue on drupal.org.

Answer (score 1):

Deactivate the BigPipe module, it causes some errors in Google Chrome when the user is logged in.

There's no error in Chrome if you aren't logged in. Firefox and Safari will still work with Kint and BigPipe enabled.